# How to build a interface that inside have array object

Tags: typescript

## Objective

Build an interface that inside will have `telephone_array`. I know that my `telephone_array` is an array that has many objects inside.

[image]

## Interfaces that I have

```
interface Client {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  telephone: string;
  created_at: string;
}


interface ClientsResponse {
  clients: Client[];
}
```

I would like to know how can I put the telephone_array inside the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add array of objects like so:

```
interface Client {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  telephone: string;
  created_at: string;
  telephone_array: Array<{
     id: string;
     telephone_number: string;
  }>
}
```

or

```
telephone_array: {
     id: string;
     telephone_number: string;
  }[]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
interface Client {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  telephone: string;
  created_at: string;
  telephone_array: {
     id: string;
     telephone_number: string;
  }[];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use another interface as an array:

```
interface Telephone {
  id: string;
  telephone_number: string;
}

interface Client {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  telephone: string;
  created_at: string;
  telephone_array: Telephone[];
}
```